Vba macro userform does not show due to system error
I have a piece of VBA code that generally works fine. It automatically saves Solidworks files and names the files based on user input from my user form.
Suddenly, when I run my Main sub, it gives the following error on the line UserParam.Show:
If I click OK it goes back to my main sub code. Then, if I try to click on my userform in my projectlist, it gives the error again:
System Error &H8007003B, there have been an unsuspected connectivity problems.

How does it suddenly appear and what do I do to solve it?

You have a couple of questions currently asking about, presumably, the same macro. Can you post all of the code from all of the modules as well as the code behind for the form?

I don't have access to solidworks, but if the VB editor is similar to Office VBA there's an option for handling errors "break in class module" (Tools >> Options >> General) which would give you a "Debug" button if your userform code has an error.
